# How to convert a data frame column to numeric type?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

How do you convert a data frame column to a numeric type?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Since (still) nobody got check-mark, I assume that you have some practical issue in mind, mostly because you haven't specified what type of vector you want to convert to `numeric`. I suggest that you should apply `transform` function in order to complete your task.

Now I'm about to demonstrate certain "conversion anomaly":

```
# create dummy data.frame
d <- data.frame(char = letters[1:5], 
                fake_char = as.character(1:5), 
                fac = factor(1:5), 
                char_fac = factor(letters[1:5]), 
                num = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Let us have a glance at `data.frame`

```
> d
  char fake_char fac char_fac num
1    a         1   1        a   1
2    b         2   2        b   2
3    c         3   3        c   3
4    d         4   4        d   4
5    e         5   5        e   5
```

and let us run:

```
> sapply(d, mode)
       char   fake_char         fac    char_fac         num 
"character" "character"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric" 
> sapply(d, class)
       char   fake_char         fac    char_fac         num 
"character" "character"    "factor"    "factor"   "integer"
```

Now you probably ask yourself *"Where's an anomaly?"* Well, I've bumped into quite peculiar things in R, and this is not **the** most confounding thing, but it can confuse you, especially if you read this before rolling into bed.

Here goes: first two columns are `character`. I've deliberately called 2<sup>nd</sup> one `fake_char`. Spot the similarity of this `character` variable with one that Dirk created in his reply. It's actually a `numerical` vector converted to `character`. 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> column are `factor`, and the last one is "purely" `numeric`.

If you utilize `transform` function, you can convert the `fake_char` into `numeric`, but not the `char` variable itself.

```
> transform(d, char = as.numeric(char))
  char fake_char fac char_fac num
1   NA         1   1        a   1
2   NA         2   2        b   2
3   NA         3   3        c   3
4   NA         4   4        d   4
5   NA         5   5        e   5
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

but if you do same thing on `fake_char` and `char_fac`, you'll be lucky, and get away with no NA's:

```
> transform(d, fake_char = as.numeric(fake_char), 
               char_fac = as.numeric(char_fac))

  char fake_char fac char_fac num
1    a         1   1        1   1
2    b         2   2        2   2
3    c         3   3        3   3
4    d         4   4        4   4
5    e         5   5        5   5
```

If you save transformed `data.frame` and check for `mode` and `class`, you'll get:

```
> D <- transform(d, fake_char = as.numeric(fake_char), 
                    char_fac = as.numeric(char_fac))

> sapply(D, mode)
       char   fake_char         fac    char_fac         num 
"character"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric" 
> sapply(D, class)
       char   fake_char         fac    char_fac         num 
"character"   "numeric"    "factor"   "numeric"   "integer"
```

So, the conclusion is: ***Yes, you can convert `character` vector into a `numeric` one, but only if it's elements are "convertible" to `numeric`.*** If there's just one `character` element in vector, you'll get error when trying to convert that vector to `numerical` one.

And just to prove my point:

```
> err <- c(1, "b", 3, 4, "e")
> mode(err)
[1] "character"
> class(err)
[1] "character"
> char <- as.numeric(err)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> char
[1]  1 NA  3  4 NA
```

And now, just for fun (or practice), try to guess the output of these commands:

```
> fac <- as.factor(err)
> fac
???
> num <- as.numeric(fac)
> num
???
```

Kind regards to Patrick Burns! =)

Comment: 'stringsAsFactors = FALSE' is important for when reading in data files.

Comment: I know this is old ... but... why did you choose transform() over df$fake_char <- as.integer(df$fake_char) ?    There are multiple ways to do the same operation in R and I get stuck understanding the "correct" way of doing it.  Thank you.

Comment: So it is absolutely impossible to turn err <- c(1, "b", 3, 4, "e") into a numeric vector? In excel, there's a button that allows you to "convert to number". making whatever value the column a numeric. I am trying to mimic that in r.

Comment: Warning != Error. You don't get an error converting mixed numeric/character to numeric, you get a warning and some NA values.

Comment: I really don't understand why there are so many different ways to convert datatypes in R, do we really need mutate, transform, apply, when all of this can be done with a simple assignment?

Comment: tl;dr use `transform`

Answer (score 167):

Something that has helped me: if you have ranges of variables to convert (or just more than one), you can use `sapply`.

A bit nonsensical but just for example:

```
data(cars)
cars[, 1:2] <- sapply(cars[, 1:2], as.factor)
```

Say columns 3, 6-15 and 37 of you dataframe need to be converted to numeric one could:

```
dat[, c(3,6:15,37)] <- sapply(dat[, c(3,6:15,37)], as.numeric)
```

Comment: as.factor in the above code makes the column character

Comment: sapply is better than transform, when handling vectors of indices rather than variable names

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy is correct, at least with my data. The original df won't take on the "converted" columns as factors; they'll remain character. If you wrap the `sapply` call in `as.data.frame()` on the right hand side, as @Mehrad Mahmoudian suggested below, it will work.

Comment: Will this work for a matrix? I'm trying it with the exact same code, yet when I check the class() of a column after, it still says "character" and not "numeric"

Answer (score 114):

if `x` is the column name of dataframe `dat`, and `x` is of type factor, use:

```
as.numeric(as.character(dat$x))
```

Comment: adding `as.character` indeed is what I was looking for. Otherwise the conversion sometimes goes wrong. At least in my case.

Comment: Why is the as.character needed? I was getting an error: `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` though I was reasonably sure that my vector had no characters / punctuations. Then i tried `as.numeric(as.character(dat$x))` and it worked. Now i'm not sure whether my column is in fact only integers or not!

Comment: If you do as.numeric to a factor it will convert the levels to numeric not the actual values. Hence as.character is needed to first convert the factor to character and then as.numeric

Comment: This is the best answer here

Answer (score 43):

I would have added a comment (cant low rating)

Just to add on user276042 and pangratz

```
dat$x = as.numeric(as.character(dat$x))
```

This will override the values of existing column x

Answer (score 20):

With the following code you can convert all data frame columns to numeric (X is the data frame that we want to convert it's columns):

```
as.data.frame(lapply(X, as.numeric))
```

and for converting whole matrix into numeric you have two ways:
Either:

```
mode(X) <- "numeric"
```

or:

```
X <- apply(X, 2, as.numeric)
```

Alternatively you can use `data.matrix` function to convert everything into numeric, although be aware that the factors might not get converted correctly, so it is safer to convert everything to `character` first:

```
X <- sapply(X, as.character)
X <- data.matrix(X)
```

I usually use **this last one** if I want **to convert to matrix and numeric simultaneously**

Answer (score 19):

While your question is strictly on numeric, there are many conversions that are difficult to understand when beginning R. I'll aim to address methods to help. This question is similar to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475874/how-can-i-convert-a-matrix-of-strings-into-a-tibble/42563612#42563612).

Type conversion can be a pain in R because (1) factors can't be converted directly to numeric, they need to be converted to character class first, (2) dates are a special case that you typically need to deal with separately, and (3) looping across data frame columns can be tricky. Fortunately, the "tidyverse" has solved most of the issues.

This solution uses `mutate_each()` to apply a function to all columns in a data frame. In this case, we want to apply the `type.convert()` function, which converts strings to numeric where it can. Because R loves factors (not sure why) character columns that should stay character get changed to factor. To fix this, the `mutate_if()` function is used to detect columns that are factors and change to character. Last, I wanted to show how lubridate can be used to change a timestamp in character class to date-time because this is also often a sticking block for beginners.

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(lubridate)

# Recreate data that needs converted to numeric, date-time, etc
data_df
#> # A tibble: 5 Ã— 9
#>             TIMESTAMP SYMBOL    EX  PRICE  SIZE  COND   BID BIDSIZ   OFR
#>                 <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#> 1 2012-05-04 09:30:00    BAC     T 7.8900 38538     F  7.89    523  7.90
#> 2 2012-05-04 09:30:01    BAC     Z 7.8850   288     @  7.88  61033  7.90
#> 3 2012-05-04 09:30:03    BAC     X 7.8900  1000     @  7.88   1974  7.89
#> 4 2012-05-04 09:30:07    BAC     T 7.8900 19052     F  7.88   1058  7.89
#> 5 2012-05-04 09:30:08    BAC     Y 7.8900 85053     F  7.88 108101  7.90

# Converting columns to numeric using "tidyverse"
data_df %>%
    mutate_all(type.convert) %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(TIMESTAMP = as_datetime(TIMESTAMP, tz = Sys.timezone()))
#> # A tibble: 5 Ã— 9
#>             TIMESTAMP SYMBOL    EX PRICE  SIZE  COND   BID BIDSIZ   OFR
#>                <dttm>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int> <chr> <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1 2012-05-04 09:30:00    BAC     T 7.890 38538     F  7.89    523  7.90
#> 2 2012-05-04 09:30:01    BAC     Z 7.885   288     @  7.88  61033  7.90
#> 3 2012-05-04 09:30:03    BAC     X 7.890  1000     @  7.88   1974  7.89
#> 4 2012-05-04 09:30:07    BAC     T 7.890 19052     F  7.88   1058  7.89
#> 5 2012-05-04 09:30:08    BAC     Y 7.890 85053     F  7.88 108101  7.90
```

Comment: Note that if you use `mutate_all(type.convert, as.is=TRUE)` instead of `mutate_all(type.convert)`, you can remove/avoid `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` to shorten the command. `as.is` is an argument in `type.convert()` that indicates whether it should convert strings as characters or as factors. By default, `as.is=FALSE` in `type.convert()` (i.e., converts strings to factor class instead of character class).

Answer (score 17):

If you run into problems with:

```
as.numeric(as.character(dat$x))
```

Take a look to your decimal marks. If they are "," instead of "." (e.g. "5,3") the above won't work.

A potential solution is:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", dat$x))
```

I believe this is quite common in some non English speaking countries.

Answer (score 15):

Tim is correct, and Shane has an omission. Here are additional examples:

```
R> df <- data.frame(a = as.character(10:15))
R> df <- data.frame(df, num = as.numeric(df$a), 
                        numchr = as.numeric(as.character(df$a)))
R> df
   a num numchr
1 10   1     10
2 11   2     11
3 12   3     12
4 13   4     13
5 14   5     14
6 15   6     15
R> summary(df)
  a          num           numchr    
 10:1   Min.   :1.00   Min.   :10.0  
 11:1   1st Qu.:2.25   1st Qu.:11.2  
 12:1   Median :3.50   Median :12.5  
 13:1   Mean   :3.50   Mean   :12.5  
 14:1   3rd Qu.:4.75   3rd Qu.:13.8  
 15:1   Max.   :6.00   Max.   :15.0  
R>
```

Our `data.frame` now has a summary of the factor column (counts) and numeric summaries of the `as.numeric()` --- which is *wrong* as it got the numeric factor levels --- and the (correct) summary of the `as.numeric(as.character())`.

Comment: My pleasure. This is one of the more silly corners of the language, and I think it featured in the older 'R Gotchas' question here.

Answer (score 14):

Universal way using `type.convert()` and `rapply()`:

```
convert_types <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is.list(x))
    x[] <- rapply(x, utils::type.convert, classes = "character",
                  how = "replace", as.is = TRUE)
    return(x)
}
d <- data.frame(char = letters[1:5], 
                fake_char = as.character(1:5), 
                fac = factor(1:5), 
                char_fac = factor(letters[1:5]), 
                num = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sapply(d, class)
#>        char   fake_char         fac    char_fac         num 
#> "character" "character"    "factor"    "factor"   "integer"
sapply(convert_types(d), class)
#>        char   fake_char         fac    char_fac         num 
#> "character"   "integer"    "factor"    "factor"   "integer"
```

Comment: This is the most flexible solution--deserves some upvotes!

Comment: Should be a top answer. Just remove `as.is = TRUE` if you want to convert your character to either numeric or factors

Comment: trying to change bunch of columns in a data.frame that has type `matrix` to numeric changes `classes=matrix` errored out first argument must be of mode character

Answer (score 6):

To convert a data frame column to numeric you just have to do:-

factor to numeric:-

```
data_frame$column <- as.numeric(as.character(data_frame$column))
```

Comment: Again, this answer doesn't add anything to the current set of answers. Also, it's not the preferred way to convert a factor to numeric. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128 for the preferred way.

Comment: A better answer was: `sapply(data_frame,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

Though others have covered the topic pretty well, I'd like to add this additional quick thought/hint.  You could use regexp to check in advance whether characters potentially consist only of numerics.

```
for(i in seq_along(names(df)){
     potential_numcol[i] <- all(!grepl("[a-zA-Z]",d[,i]))
}
# and now just convert only the numeric ones
d <- sapply(d[,potential_numcol],as.numeric)
```

For more sophisticated regular expressions and a neat why to learn/experience their power see this really nice website: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Considering there might exist char columns, this is based on @Abdou in [Get column types of excel sheet automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735346/get-column-types-of-excel-sheet-automatically) answer:

```
makenumcols<-function(df){
  df<-as.data.frame(df)
  df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
  cond <- apply(df, 2, function(x) {
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    all(suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(x))))
  })
  numeric_cols <- names(df)[cond]
  df[,numeric_cols] <- sapply(df[,numeric_cols], as.numeric)
  return(df)
}
df<-makenumcols(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dataframe has multiple types of columns, some characters, some numeric try the following to convert just the columns that contain numeric values to numeric:

```
for (i in 1:length(data[1,])){
  if(length(as.numeric(data[,i][!is.na(data[,i])])[!is.na(as.numeric(data[,i][!is.na(data[,i])]))])==0){}
  else {
    data[,i]<-as.numeric(data[,i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with **hablar::convert**

To easily convert multiple columns to different data types you can use `hablar::convert`. Simple syntax: `df %>% convert(num(a))` converts the column a from df to numeric.

**Detailed example**

Lets convert all columns of `mtcars` to character.

```
df <- mtcars %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% as_tibble()

> df
# A tibble: 32 x 11
   mpg   cyl   disp  hp    drat  wt    qsec  vs    am    gear  carb 
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.62  16.46 0     1     4     4    
 2 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.875 17.02 0     1     4     4    
 3 22.8  4     108   93    3.85  2.32  18.61 1     1     4     1
```

With `hablar::convert`:

```
library(hablar)

# Convert columns to integer, numeric and factor
df %>% 
  convert(int(cyl, vs),
          num(disp:wt),
          fct(gear))
```

results in:

```
# A tibble: 32 x 11
   mpg     cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt qsec     vs am    gear  carb 
   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr> <fct> <chr>
 1 21        6  160    110  3.9   2.62 16.46     0 1     4     4    
 2 21        6  160    110  3.9   2.88 17.02     0 1     4     4    
 3 22.8      4  108     93  3.85  2.32 18.61     1 1     4     1    
 4 21.4      6  258    110  3.08  3.22 19.44     1 0     3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about preserving the factors, and want to apply it to any column that can get converted to numeric, I used the script below.
if df is your original dataframe, you can use the script below.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(x)), as.numeric(x),  x)))
```

I referenced [Shane's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters) and [Joran's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638377/test-for-numeric-elements-in-a-character-string) solution btw

Answer (score 0):

In my PC (R v.3.2.3), `apply` or `sapply` give error. `lapply` works well.

```
dt[,2:4] <- lapply(dt[,2:4], function (x) as.factor(as.numeric(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert character to numeric you have to convert it into factor by applying

```
BankFinal1 <- transform(BankLoan,   LoanApproval=as.factor(LoanApproval))
BankFinal1 <- transform(BankFinal1, LoanApp=as.factor(LoanApproval))
```

You have to make two columns with the same data, because one column cannot convert into numeric. If you do one conversion it gives the below error

```
transform(BankData, LoanApp=as.numeric(LoanApproval))
```

> ```
> Warning message:
>   In eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) :
>   NAs introduced by coercion
> ```

so, after doing two column of the same data apply

```
BankFinal1 <- transform(BankFinal1, LoanApp      = as.numeric(LoanApp), 
                                    LoanApproval = as.numeric(LoanApproval))
```

it will transform the character to numeric successfully

Answer (score 0):

`df` ist your dataframe. `x` is a column of `df` you want to convert

```
as.numeric(factor(df$x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to numeric **only columns with digits** with or without decimal separator

```
# detect which columsn have numeric characters (digits) with or without decimal separator "."
columns_with_digits <- sapply(df, function(x) 
  all(grepl("^\\d+\\.?\\d*$", x))  
)

# run as.numeric only in the detected columns 
df[, columns_with_digits] <- data.frame(lapply(df[, columns_with_digits], as.numeric))
```

### See an example with `iris` below

```
library(dplyr) # for glimpse

# get example data
df <- iris

# convert from numeric columns to charactere
df$Sepal.Length <- as.character(df$Sepal.Length)
df$Sepal.Width <- as.character(df$Sepal.Width)
df$Petal.Length <- as.character(df$Petal.Length)
df$Petal.Width <- as.character(df$Petal.Width)

glimpse(df)
```

Check the data with `glimpse()`

```
>glimpse(df)
Rows: 150
Columns: 5
$ Sepal.Length <chr> "5.1", "4.9", "4.7", "4.6", "5",…
$ Sepal.Width  <chr> "3.5", "3", "3.2", "3.1", "3.6",…
$ Petal.Length <chr> "1.4", "1.4", "1.3", "1.5", "1.4…
$ Petal.Width  <chr> "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2…
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, …
```

##### Detect which columns have numeric characters (digits) with or without decimal separator point (.) using regular expressions (regex)

```
# detect which columns have numeric characters (digits) with or without decimal separator (.)
columns_with_digits <- sapply(df, function(x) 
  all(grepl("^\\d+\\.?\\d*$", x))
)
# where: 
# ^ indicates the begginig of the string
# \\d+ corresponds to a sequence of one or more digits 
# \\.? indicates the that points is optional (it can appear zero or more times due the ?)
# \\d* corresponds to zero or more digits after the 'optional' point 
# $ indicates the end of the string
```

##### Proceed to convert with lapply

```
# run as.numeric only in the detected columns 
df[, columns_with_digits] <- data.frame(lapply(df[, columns_with_digits], as.numeric))
```

Check final output

```
# check again 
glimpse(df)
```

```
Columns: 5
$ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.…
$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.…
$ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.…
$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.…
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, …
```