# Check if string contains ONLY NUMBERS or ONLY CHARACTERS (R)

Tags: r, regex

I have these three strings:

```
letters <- "abc" 
numbers <- "123" 
mix <- "b1dd"
```

How can I check which one of these strings contains LETTERS ONLY or NUMBERS ONLY (in R)?

`letters` should only be TRUE in the LETTERS ONLY check

`numbers` should only be TRUE in the NUMBERS ONLY check

`mix` should be FALSE in every situation

I tried several approaches now but none of them really worked for me :(

For example if I use

```
grepl("[A-Za-z]", letters)
```

It works well for `letters`, but it would also works for `mix`, what I don't want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you need to persist your regex

```
all_num <- "123"
all_letters <- "abc"
mixed <- "123abc"


grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", all_num, perl = T) #will be false
grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", all_letters, perl = T) #will be true
grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", mixed, perl=T) #will be false
```

Comment: `perl=TRUE` is not necessary.

Comment: I do it just to be safe @fexjoo if it answers your need then please pick my answer to close the Q

Comment: Try `all_letters2 <- "ü"` Using `[[:alpha:]]` might be safer.

Answer (score 34):

```
# Check that it doesn't match any non-letter
letters_only <- function(x) !grepl("[^A-Za-z]", x)

# Check that it doesn't match any non-number
numbers_only <- function(x) !grepl("\\D", x)

letters <- "abc" 
numbers <- "123" 
mix <- "b1dd"

letters_only(letters)
## [1] TRUE

letters_only(numbers)
## [1] FALSE

letters_only(mix)
## [1] FALSE

numbers_only(letters)
## [1] FALSE

numbers_only(numbers)
## [1] TRUE

numbers_only(mix)
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: numbers_only does works only for integers. I suggest using `numbers_only <- function(x) suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(k))))` if you want to include fractions in the test, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129124/how-to-determine-if-a-character-vector-is-a-valid-numeric-or-integer-vector?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Mikko Yes, I interpreted the request as "Check if every character in the string is a digit."  So it wouldn't match fractions, decimals, scientific notation, or even integers with a thousands separator.  If one wants to recognize "strings that can represent a number", it becomes culture dependent.  E.g., under American cultural conventions a number can contain multiple commas (thousands separators), but only one period (the decimal point), and no spaces.  But in many other countries the role of comma and period is reversed, or a space is used as the thousands or millions separator.

Comment: Shouldn't this be !grepl("\\d", x)?. The \\D didn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @BICube `grepl("\\D", x)` will match if `x` contains any non-digit.  (Capital D for non-digit).  And so, `!grepl("\\D", x)` will match if `x` _doesn't_ contain any non-digit -- i.e., if `x` contains _only_ digits.  (Whereas, `!grepl("\\d", x)` will match if `x` contains _no_ digits.)

Answer (score 7):

Using the `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
all_num <- "123"
all_letters <- "abc"
mixed <- "123abc"

# LETTERS ONLY
str_detect(all_num, "^[:alpha:]+$")
str_detect(all_letters, "^[:alpha:]+$")
str_detect(mixed, "^[:alpha:]+$")

# NUMBERS ONLY
str_detect(all_num, "^[:digit:]+$")
str_detect(all_letters, "^[:digit:]+$")
str_detect(mixed, "^[:digit:]+$")
```