# Regex for "is every character in string numeric?"

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm wondering what regex pattern I could use to detect if every character in a string is numeric.

So, here's what I'm thinking that isn't working:

```
stringr::str_detect("311apple", "[0-9]")
#> [1] TRUE
```

That statement is `TRUE` because there exists a numeric character in that string, but I'm trying to find a pattern so that it's only `TRUE` if **every** character is numeric.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use `^[0-9]+$`.

Comment: FWIW I saw the answer that this is a "duplicate" of, but it doesn't look like the answers are applicable to R.

Also, maybe I can re-think this as a "detect if there are any non-numeric characters" potentially.

Comment: Thanks for the response @WiktorStribiżew. Want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: There are a lot of patterns that are applicable in R, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011537/3832970, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011683/3832970

Comment: Ah, I missed the ones near the bottom. My apologies. Should I delete?

Comment: Another good R solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43195631/3832970