# Delete row if contains character in R

Tags: r, character, numeric

Say we have a column in a df that is contains mostly numeric values, but a few rows are character:

```
row1 <- c(2, 3, 5, 1, 0) 
row2 <- c(5, 2, "char", "word", 10) 
df <- data.frame(row1, row2)
```

```
> df
row1  row2
2      5
5      char
1      word
3      2
0      10
```

How can I remove rows in the entire `df` that contain a character in `row2`, such that the final `df` should look like this:

```
> df
row1  row2
2      5
3      2
0      10
```

Comment: Related: [Check if string contains ONLY NUMBERS or ONLY CHARACTERS (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195519/check-if-string-contains-only-numbers-or-only-characters-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to provide a fuller answer here so you can understand how to solve this issue.

Using your vector `row2`, we can coerce that data from character type to numeric type using the `as.numeric()` function. R will do the best it can — it's easy to coerce `"2"` or `"5"` to numbers, but R won't know what to do with `"word"` or `"char"` so it will return `NA`s.

```
as.numeric(row2)
```

The `is.na()` function can then return a logical vector saying whether each of those elements is an `NA` value.

```
is.na(as.numeric(row2))
```

That logic can be reversed by adding a `!` as a prefix.

```
!is.na(as.numeric(row2))
```

Finally, that logical vector can be used to subset a data structure.

```
row2[!is.na(as.numeric(row2))]
df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$row2)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df$row2))),]  


df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$row2)),]
```

Edited: Add solution without `as.character` (following @markus comment)

Comment: `df$row2` is of type character already.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  filter(!is.na(as.numeric(row2)))
```

Comment: isn't it a little bit excessive to load the entire tidyverse just for the filter function? :D

Comment: If you only open R to run these two lines of code, maybe. But I would assume that‘s hardly ever the case.