# Check whether an element in a character vector can be converted to numeric in R

Tags: r, vector, null, character

How can I check whether an element of a character vector can be converted to numeric or not? To be more precise, when the element is a float or an integer it can be converted to numeric without any problems, but when it is a string the warning: `“NAs introduced by coercion”` occurs. I was  able to indirectly check by the index of the NA value. However, it would be much cleaner to be able to do this without getting a warning.

```r
cat1 <- c("1.12354","1.4548","1.9856","some_string")
cat2 <- c("1.45678","1.1478","1.9565","1.32315")
target <- c(0,1,1,0)
df <- data.frame(cat1, cat2, target)
catCols <- c("cat1", "cat2")

for(col in catCols){
a <- as.numeric(unique(df[[col]]))
if(length(which(is.na(a))) != 0){
print(col)
print(which(is.na(a)))
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? The `as.numeric` function warns you if you have some non-coercible numbers. You just want to suppress the warnings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for numeric elements in a character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638377/test-for-numeric-elements-in-a-character-string)

Comment: You either convert the entire vector to numeric, or you leave it as string.  What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to determine the element and the column this warning occurs at

Comment: @nicola The goal is to determine the value and the column this warning occurs at but preferably without getting the warning. Using another method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, you can use regex to find if all the values in a column are either an integer or float.

```
can_convert_to_numeric <- function(x) {
  all(grepl('^(?=.)([+-]?([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]+))?)$', x, perl = TRUE))  
}

sapply(df[catCols], can_convert_to_numeric)
# cat1  cat2 
#FALSE  TRUE
```

Alternatively, to get values that cannot be converted to numeric we can use `grep` as :

```
values_which_cannot_be_numeric <- function(x) {
  grep('^(?=.)([+-]?([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]+))?)$', x, perl = TRUE, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
}

lapply(df[catCols], values_which_cannot_be_numeric)

#$cat1
#[1] "some_string"

#$cat2
#character(0)
```

Regex taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23059703/3962914).

---

If you use `type.convert` you don't have to worry about this at all.

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
str(df)

#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ cat1  : chr  "1.12354" "1.4548" "1.9856" "some_string"
# $ cat2  : num  1.46 1.15 1.96 1.32
# $ target: int  0 1 1 0
```

Comment: What about numeric literals with exponents?  What about hexadecimals?

Comment: @RonakSkah I also want to find the value which cannot be converted to numeric

Comment: @moli  To get the values which cannot be converted to numeric, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to write a function returning the indices of the `NA` values to be applied to the columns you want.

```
check_num <- function(x){
  y <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
  if(anyNA(y)){
    which(is.na(y))
  } else invisible(NULL)
}
lapply(df[catCols], check_num)
#$cat1
#[1] 4
#
#$cat2
#NULL
```

The function above returns `NULL` if all values can be converted to numeric. This next function follows the same method of determining which vector elements can be converted but returns `integer(0)` if all can be converted.

```
check_num2 <- function(x){
  y <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
  which(is.na(y))
}
lapply(df[catCols], check_num2)
#$cat1
#[1] 4
#
#$cat2
#integer(0)
```