# Why am I getting an error when trying to convert "numerical" degrees to DMS using dd2dms()?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert two columns of data, lat and long coordinates, from dd to dms using;

```
dd2dms(y, NS = TRUE)
```

but when I do get the error

```
Error in Math.factor(dd) : sign not meaningful for factors
```

I know there are good answers out there to help with converting to different types of data, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type). Unfortunately however, this does not solve my problem because my data is in fact, numerical.

My data is coming from the US Census Bureau shapefiles available [here](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/file-download). This is the code I am using.

```
require(rgdal)
UAP=readOGR(dsn = "C:/Directory", layer = "file")
```

The columns I want to convert look like this

```
 INTPTLAT10   INTPTLON10
+40.7185358 -084.0757264
+40.7038198 -084.1723263
```

So first I try:

```
> y = UAP@data$INTPTLAT10
> sapply(y, mode)
[1] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" #etc...
> dd2dms(y)
Error in Math.factor(dd) : sign not meaningful for factors
```

I tried a couple other simple tests to try and diagnose where my problem was.

```
> x=UAP@data[14]
> sapply(x, mode)
INTPTLAT10 
 "numeric"
> dd2dms(x, NS = TRUE)
Error in Math.data.frame(dd) : 
  non-numeric variable in data frame: INTPTLAT10

>x = +40.5987
>sapply(x)
[1] "numeric"
>dd2dms(x, NS = TRUE)
[1] 40d35'55.32"N
```

I need to get these coordinates into DMS so that I can apply the distance formula (which requires the use of trig functions so they must be in DMS format). But I am confused about where this error is popping up from.

Any help would be appreciated! I have been struggling with this for days!

Comment: I suspicious that the unreferenced package from which you are getting `readOGR` keeps coordinates in factor class so that the "plus-signs" will display as a geographer would expect. (Minus signs would display properly if stored as numeric.) `mode` is less informative than `class` in such an instance.

Comment: Thank @DWin, I just included the package that I used for the readOGR command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is that `y` is probably a factor, as Hong Ooi implied.
  Example:

```
Rgames> foo<-as.factor(1:5)
Rgames> mode(foo)
[1] "numeric"
Rgames> class(foo)
[1] "factor"
```

So convert, e.g. as   `yy <- as.numeric(as.character(y))`  and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your data might have some non-numeric entries buried somewhere, eg strings like "NA" or whatever. When R sees them, it assumes the whole column is character, which is probably then being converted into a factor.

Note that:

- `mode(f)` for a factor `f` is numeric (since factors are internally stored as numbers). You want `class(f)`.
- if `x` is a primitive vector, then `sapply(x, mode)` is needlessly complex. You want just `mode(x)`.