# xlsx package in R converting numeric dataframe to text in xlsx file

Tags: r, dataframe, export-to-excel, xlsx

I have a dataframe in R consisting of 0s and 1s.
When I write it to an xlsx file and open this file in microsoft spreadsheet, it show an error on each cell with number : "number stored as text". Is there a way to fix it in R. Here is a sample of what I did:

```
write.xlsx(result,"test.xlsx",sheetName="Sheet1",row.names=F) 
sapply(result,mode) 
GO_ids GO.0007411 GO.0006915 GO.0006914 GO.0006464 GO.0006298 GO.0018108 
 "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric" 
GO.0006355 GO.0007155 GO.0030036 GO.0030155 
 "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe the `write.xlsx()` function has that ability. But you could write a VBA macro in Excel to automatically convert to numeric...

Answer (score 1):

Your data is probably a factor:

```
> not_a_number <- factor(c(1, 2, 3))
> mode(not_a_number)
[1] "numeric"
> typeof(not_a_number)
[1] "integer"
> class(not_a_number)
[1] "factor"
> str(not_a_number)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
```

write.xlsx writes factors as strings.

See also [How to convert a data frame column to numeric type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type)