# How can I convert a matrix of strings into a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, xts

I'm given some data in an .rData file. The format is an `xts` object in character mode. (I realise this is an unusual format, but I have no control over it)

```
> head(trades)
                    SYMBOL EX  PRICE    SIZE    COND BID    BIDSIZ   OFR   
2012-05-04 09:30:00 "BAC"  "T" "7.89"   "38538" "F"  "7.89" "523"    "7.9" 
2012-05-04 09:30:01 "BAC"  "Z" "7.885"  "288"   "@"  "7.88" "61033"  "7.9" 
2012-05-04 09:30:03 "BAC"  "X" "7.89"   "1000"  "@"  "7.88" "1974"   "7.89"
2012-05-04 09:30:07 "BAC"  "T" "7.89"   "19052" "F"  "7.88" "1058"   "7.89"
2012-05-04 09:30:08 "BAC"  "Y" "7.89"   "85053" "F"  "7.88" "108101" "7.9" 
2012-05-04 09:30:09 "BAC"  "D" "7.8901" "10219" "@"  "7.89" "268"    "7.9" 

> mode(trades)
'character'
```

I would like to process this data by converting into a saner format, namely a tibble, so that I can store the columns as datetimes, doubles and integers.

I've managed to achieve this with the following code:

```
> trades_ =  bind_cols(data_frame(DATE=index(trades)), as_data_frame(coredata(trades))) %>%
    mutate_at(as.numeric, .cols=vars(PRICE, BID, OFR)) %>%
    mutate_at(as.integer, .cols=vars(SIZE, BIDSIZ, OFRSIZ))

> head(trades_)
# A tibble: 6 × 10
                 DATE SYMBOL    EX  PRICE  SIZE  COND   BID BIDSIZ   OFR
               <dttm>  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <int> <chr> <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
1 2012-05-04 09:30:00    BAC     T 7.8900 38538     F  7.89    523  7.90   
2 2012-05-04 09:30:01    BAC     Z 7.8850   288     @  7.88  61033  7.90
3 2012-05-04 09:30:03    BAC     X 7.8900  1000     @  7.88   1974  7.89   
4 2012-05-04 09:30:07    BAC     T 7.8900 19052     F  7.88   1058  7.89   
5 2012-05-04 09:30:08    BAC     Y 7.8900 85053     F  7.88 108101  7.90
6 2012-05-04 09:30:09    BAC     D 7.8901 10219     @  7.89    268  7.90
```

I'm wondering if there's already a built-in function for this. Something that looks at each column of the `trades` matrix and figures out whether it's a column of integers, doubles, etc and converts it to the appropriate type.

This is the sort of thing that a csv parser would do.

Comment: `?type.convert`, which is as you guessed, used as a helper function for `read.csv` `read.table` etc.

Comment: You're probably better off explicitly setting the types like this. Tracking down bugs when the computer guesses wrong can be a pain.

Comment: @HongOoi: I think you might be right, `type.convert` didn't like `"1e+05"` in the `SIZE` column...

Comment: Another simple option: write it out and read it in again.

Comment: @user357269 - are you sure about that? `type.convert(c("1000","1.25","1e1","1e+05"))` returns a numeric vector for me.

Comment: @thelatemail, yeah, sorry if I was unclear, my problem is that `SIZE` ought to be an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from an authoritative answer, but I ended up doing this:

```
smarter_type_convert = function (vector) {
    converted_vector = type.convert(vector)
    if (is.numeric(converted_vector)) {
        int_vector = as.integer(converted_vector)
        if (isTRUE(all.equal(int_vector, converted_vector, check.attributes=FALSE))) {
            int_vector
        } else {
            converted_vector
        }
    } else {
        converted_vector
    }
}

trades %>% coredata %>% as_data_frame %>% mutate_all(smarter_type_convert)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that a data frame is the right approach since you are working with multiple classes in the same frame. `xts` doesn't allow multiple classes so coercion rules force you to work with characters instead of numbers.

Here's a solution so you don't have to specifically call out each column. I use the `tidyquant` package which is made for working with quantitative data within the "tidyverse" (i.e. using "tidy" data frames). It also has some nice functions to convert to and from `xts`, `matrix` and other time series classes that contain row names.

First, I recreate the data.

```
> trades_xts
                    SYMBOL EX  PRICE    SIZE    COND BID    BIDSIZ   OFR    
2012-05-04 09:30:00 "BAC"  "T" "7.8900" "38538" "F"  "7.89" "523"    "7.90" 
2012-05-04 09:30:01 "BAC"  "Z" "7.8850" "288"   "@"  "7.88" "61033"  "7.90" 
2012-05-04 09:30:03 "BAC"  "X" "7.8900" "1000"  "@"  "7.88" "1974"   "7.89" 
2012-05-04 09:30:07 "BAC"  "T" "7.8900" "19052" "F"  "7.88" "1058"   "7.89"
2012-05-04 09:30:08 "BAC"  "Y" "7.8900" "85053" "F"  "7.88" "108101" "7.90" 
2012-05-04 09:30:09 "BAC"  "D" "7.8901" "10219" "@"  "7.89" "268"    "7.90"
```

Next, I use tidy functions to clean the data. It's a little longer than your script, but you don't need to worry about which columns have which data type (with the exception of the xts index). Note that I'm using the `tidyquant::as_tibble()` functions to convert the `xts` row names to a column. I use `mutate_each` to apply the `type.convert` function to each column. Unfortunately base R loves the `factor` class so I add an additional step to convert to `character`. The last two steps just clean up the date-time column using `dplyr::rename` and `lubridate::as_datetime`, which `tidyquant` loads for you.

```
> library(tidyquant)
> trades_xts %>%
    as_tibble(preserve_row_names = TRUE) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(type.convert)) %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    rename(DATE = row.names) %>%
    mutate(DATE = as_datetime(DATE, tz = Sys.timezone())) 
    # A tibble: 6 × 9
                 DATE SYMBOL    EX  PRICE  SIZE  COND   BID BIDSIZ   OFR
               <dttm>  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <int> <chr> <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
1 2012-05-04 09:30:00    BAC     T 7.8900 38538     F  7.89    523  7.90
2 2012-05-04 09:30:01    BAC     Z 7.8850   288     @  7.88  61033  7.90
3 2012-05-04 09:30:03    BAC     X 7.8900  1000     @  7.88   1974  7.89
4 2012-05-04 09:30:07    BAC     T 7.8900 19052     F  7.88   1058  7.89
5 2012-05-04 09:30:08    BAC     Y 7.8900 85053     F  7.88 108101  7.90
6 2012-05-04 09:30:09    BAC     D 7.8901 10219     @  7.89    268  7.90
```

Comment: `type.convert` has `as.is` argument. Setting it to `TRUE` prevent conversion to factor.