# only some characters change to numeric when converting in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, na

I need to convert the Votes column variable on the following data frame from character to numeric without adding NA’s

```
 > res
                  Party              Votes                  
 1 Progressive Liberal Party         28,599           
 2    Free National Movement         19,781           
 3 Commonwealth Labour Party            254            
 4              Independents            753            
 5       Invalid/blank votes                             
 6                     Total         49,387            

 > str(res)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  5 variables:
$ Party: chr  "Progressive Liberal Party" "Free National Movement" 
"Commonwealth Labour Party" "Independents" ...
$ Votes: chr  "28,599" "19,781" "254" "753" ...
```

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type?rq=1) on StackOverflow with a number of suggestions
and I tried the following methods

- Using `transform`

  ```
  D <- transform(res, Votes = as.numeric(Votes))
  ```

  However, this leads to only a few numbers converting to numeric. See below

  ```
   1    NA
   2    NA
   3   254
   4   753
   5    NA
   6    NA
   7    NA
  ```
- using `as.character` and then using `as.numeric`

  ```
    as.numeric(as.character(res$Votes))
  ```

  But that leads to the same issue

  ```
  NA  NA 254 753  NA  NA  NA
  ```

How do I ensure that all numbers in the vote column are converted to numeric?

Comment: First get rid of the commas: `sub(",", "", res$Votes)`. Then `as.numeric/as.character`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert numbers that have commas, dollar signs, or similar formatting, use `parse_number()` from the *readr* package.

```
> library(readr)
> parse_number("28,599")
[1] 28599
```

Comment: You can also just use `readr::read_csv` to import your CSV file in the first place, and avoid the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

The comma is throwing it off, you need to remove it first using `gsub`.

```
res$Votes <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", res$Votes))
```

Comment: In my comment above, I forgot that `gsub` returns `character`, there's no need to use it again.