# Transform all factor columns to their type (char, numeric)?

Tags: r, dataframe, position, factors

I have a data frame (df) with some factorized columns say:

```
col1 (numeric factor) col2 (char factor) col3 (ord factor p < r < c)
1                     a                  r 
2                     b                  p
3                     c                  c
```

Where `1,2,3 are numeric factors, a,b,c are char factors and col3 p,r,c are ord factor column.`

Please advise how can I transform all of them in few lines to numbers and chars
to make col1 of type numeric, col2 and col3 of type char.
And please help me how can I locate ord factor variables in dataframe?

Thanks.

Comment: `str(df)` or `sapply(df,class)` will identify the types of all columns, including ordered factors.

Comment: For details behind the answer of @akrun, please check the answers to these questions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type)

Answer (score 4):

We could do this by looping through the columns, convert to `character` and then use `type.convert`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c('1', '2', '3'), col2 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
             col3 = ordered(c('p', 'r', 'c')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dig some with trial and error and I think this is an elegant solution:
names(x[sapply(x, is.ordered)])
What do you experts think?