# fread reading data structure wrong with quotes

Tags: r, data.table

I have a 5 G file data to load. fread seems to be a fast way to load them but it reads all my data structures wrong. It looks like it is the quotes that result the problem.

```
# Codes. I don't know how to put raw csv data here.   
dt<-fread("data.csv",header=T)
dt2<-read.csv("data.csv",header=T)
str(dt)
str(dt2)
```

This is the output. All data structures of fread variables are char regardless whether it is num or char.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's curious that `fread` didn't use numeric for the id column, maybe some entries contain non-numeric values?

The documentation suggests the use of `colClasses` parameter.

```
dt <- fread("data.csv", header = T, colClasses = c("numeric", "character"))
```

---

The documentation has a warning for using this parameter:

> A character vector of classes (named or unnamed), as read.csv. Or a named list of vectors of column names or numbers, see examples. colClasses in fread is intended for rare overrides, not for routine use. fread will only promote a column to a higher type if colClasses requests it. It won't downgrade a column to a lower type since NAs would result. You have to coerce such columns afterwards yourself, if you really require data loss.

Comment: I tried the colClasses = c("integer", "character"). The str is still char for the id.

Comment: thats simply the printing method.

Comment: The read.csv(base) correctly reads the data, even for the id. The fread treats every single variable as char

Comment: use base R and tell me the output of the following, `as.integer(dt2$id)`, are there any warnings. `data.table::fread` is usually pretty clever and can figure out column types.

Comment: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Comment: OUTPUT: [1000] NA
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 498974 entries ]

Comment: looks like some entries have a character to me, run this to see: `length(grep("[[:alpha:]]", dt2$id))`. Actually lets try numeric instead of integer, try the updated post.

Comment: I have run the dt2, there are some NAs. length(grep("[[:alpha:]]", dt2$id))
[1] 200

Comment: try `colClasses = c("numeric", "character")`

Comment: Still everything char

Comment: Can't help anymore then, I would manually convert after read-in at your own risk. It seems as if something is odd in the data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the `fread` command will detect the type in a particular column and then assign the **lowest** type it can to that column based on what the column contains. From the [fread documentation:](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/fread)

> A sample of 1,000 rows is used to determine column types (100 rows
>   from 10 points). **The lowest type for each column is chosen from the
>   ordered list: logical, integer, integer64, double, character.** This
>   enables fread to allocate exactly the right number of rows, with
>   columns of the right type, up front once. The file may of course still
>   contain data of a higher type in rows outside the sample. In that
>   case, the **column types are bumped mid read and the data read on
>   previous rows is coerced.**

This means that if you have a column with mostly numeric type values it might assign the column as `numeric`, but then if it finds any `character` type values later on it will coerce anything read up to that point to `character` type.

You can read about these type conversions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2293313/9374673), but the long and short of it seems to be that trying to convert a `character` column to `numeric` for values that are not numeric will result in those values being converted to `NA`, or a double might be converted to an integer, leading to a loss of precision.

You might be okay with this loss of precision, but `fread` will not allow you to do this conversion using `colClasses`. You might want to go in and remove non-numeric values yourself.