# R: Convert characters to numeric in data.frame with unknown column classes

Tags: r, dataframe, character, numeric

There is a nice discussion of how to convert character into numerics in this SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type).
Maybe I missed something in that post, but what would one do if one does not know which columns are "convertable" (if any) ?
Is it possible to check for convertability ?
In addition, I usually suppress factor conversion (like character better) - so characters should be characters (not factors).

```
df <- data.frame(a=as.character(c(NA, 1/3)), b=letters[1:2], c=c('1|2', '4|2'), d=as.character(3:4), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Then apply ... some function `f` ... to get:

```
str(f(df))
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: num  NA 0.333
 $ b: chr  "a" "b"
 $ c: chr  "1|2" "4|2"
 $ d: int  3 4
```

How to achieve this for any data.frame not known beforehand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this (not very elegant though).

```
fun1 <- function(i) {
  if (!all(is.na(as.numeric(df[, i])))){
    as.numeric(df[, i])
  } else {
    df[, i]
  }
}

df1 <- "names<-"(cbind.data.frame(lapply(seq_along(df), fun1),
                                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE), names(df))

> str(df1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: num  NA 0.333
 $ b: chr  "a" "b"
 $ c: chr  "1|2" "4|2"
 $ d: num  3 4
```

Or more generally:

```
convertiblesToNumeric <- function(x){
  x2 <- cbind.data.frame(lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    if (!all(is.na(as.numeric(x[, i])))){
      as.numeric(x[, i])
      } else {
        x[, i]
        }
    }), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(x2) <- names(x)
  return(x2)
}

df1 <- convertiblesToNumeric(df)
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: num  NA 0.333
 $ b: chr  "a" "b"
 $ c: chr  "1|2" "4|2"
 $ d: num  3 4
```

Comment: But works. What is happening with the "names<-" statement ?

Comment: You could also do `df1 <- cbind.data.frame(.); names(df1) <- names(df)` in two lines of code.

Comment: Try `?"names<-"` and see [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls) for some explanation.

Comment: Perhaps your function - for completeness - should allow a second parameter for `df` when ones data.frame is named something different (than `df`). As in `fun1 <- function(i, df) {...}` and then call `lapply(seq_along(DF), fun1, df=DF)`

Comment: Cool. And even put `as.character( x[, i])` inside `as.numeric( ... )` both places in case you get a factor (otherwise you convert the levels).

Comment: That would not work as expected. Better is to transform all to character with `df[] <- sapply(df, as.character)` before applying the function. Or include a line `x <- cbind.data.frame(sapply(x, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` into the function to do that within.