# unable to export same format data from csv file

Tags: r

I have a `.csv` file that contains 50 columns including text, numbers, amount and percentage. when I am exporting data to `.xlsx` in r all amount and percentage columns are converted to text. Any help?

my code below :

```
datafile <- choose.files("", caption = " Select files ")
data <- read.csv(datafile, header = TRUE, sep = "," )

write.xlsx(data, file = "abc.xlsx" , sheetName = "UtilizationReportGRE", row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 2):

Write.xlsx converts factors to strings. Change your data to make the numeric columns numeric and so on before using write.xlsx. See also [How to convert a data frame column to numeric type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type)

Comment: I used transform but all the values of the column converted to #N/A