# nested sapply to convert a data.frame of integer values to double while retaining decimal values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, casting, sapply

Good day all,

So I have been struggling with this for a couple of days.

I have a data.frame of about 20,000 rows and 18 columns (20000 X 18) of integer values, about half of which are negative values and some zeros.

i.e. if I do

```
sapply(fj, typeof)
```

I get -

```
      volc.X.x       volc.y.x       volc.X.y       volc.y.y     volc.X.x.x     volc.y.x.x     volc.X.y.y     volc.y.y.y   volc.X.x.x.x 
     "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer" 
  volc.y.x.x.x   volc.X.y.y.y   volc.y.y.y.y volc.X.x.x.x.x volc.y.x.x.x.x volc.X.y.y.y.y volc.y.y.y.y.y         volc.X         volc.y 
     "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"
```

I know  can do

```
fj_2<-as.data.frame(sapply(fj_1, as.double))
```

This, however, causes issues with how factors are dealt with, so taking clues from these posts -

[How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/2141709)
&
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2288510/2141709

I would have to do something like

```
as.double(as.character(fj$volc.X.x))
```

or in terms of `sapply`

```
fj_2<-as.data.frame(sapply(fj, as.character))
and then
fj_2<-as.data.frame(sapply(fj, as.double))
```

This way, however, the first `sapply` with `as.character` does not change my columns to character type, and as such when I run `sapply` with `as.double` - it converts all columns to double type, but the numbers are rounded off - removing all decimals, and negative values are converted to positive values.

I tried to run a "nested" `sapply` like this

```
fj_2<-as.data.frame(sapply((sapply(fj, as.character)), as.double))
```

but this just ends up returning a single column of 360,000 values, though the numbers are in their original format and not rounded out.

What changes do I need to make? I hope I was clear about my issue.

Thanks

Comment: For the most part, you should forget about `sapply()`. (Use `vapply()` if you really need the simplification part; it's safer to program with.) Instead, use `lapply()`, whose results will keep types and so can easily be coerced to a data frame provided all elements are of the same length.

Comment: `factors` are stored as integers internally. You should use `class` i.e `sapply(fj, class)` to get the class of each column. Try `fj[] <- lapply(fj, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` if you convert factors to numeric.